# How to hide command prompt windows using ExecDos command

Tags: windows, batch-file, xampp, nsis

I want to execute three bat files in my script, the problem is when i run these `.bat` files directly using `execwait`, command windows gets open, I want to hide these command windows but its not working. My code is of just 3 lines.

```
ExecDos::exec '"catalina_start.bat"' 
ExecDos::exec '"mysql_start.bat"' 
ExecDos::exec '"apache_start.bat"'
```

I also tried this `nsExec` command but still no solution:

```
nsExec::Exec "cmd /C catalina_start.bat"
nsExec::Exec "cmd /C mysql_start.bat"
nsExec::Exec "cmd /C apache_start.bat"
```

A little background on these `.bat` files, Actually these are files of xampp setup, xampp internally uses these files to start tomcat, mysql, and apache.
The problem I am facing is that only first bat file gets executed, i. e. tomcat gets started (I can see that in xampp console), but then script dosen't move ahead, sql and apache is not getting started.

Comment: Edit the title so people will know the context is nsis script

Comment: As you can see in the documentation of [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt) it doesn't show the console window. So either your batch files spawn new console windows with `start .....` inside or you've encountered a bug in NSIS installer in which case you should contact their support forum or whatever they have.

Comment: @Some1Pr0: that's what the question tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

Does the batch-file contain `pause` or something else that prevents it from completing?

You should start off just by using something like `ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /k "$InstDir\catalina_start.bat"'` (or `/c`) so you can see the text written to the console including any errors. Once it works correctly you can switch to one of the exec plugins that hides the console...

Comment: Hi , I tried `ExecWait '"cmd.exe" /k "$InstDir\catalina_start.bat"'` for all three bat files but it is not working . Like you said the bat files is not getting completely executed , first one command window gets open up then until i manually close this command window the second bat file does not run , but I want all three command windows to remain open and also i want to minimize them, how can i achieve this . Plzz help.

Comment: Add "exit" or "cls" at the end of the batch file. You must also change /K to /C to actually close the window...

Answer (score 1):

You can change command windows from `cmd /C catalina_start.bat` to `start /Min cmd /c catalina_start.bat` it will hide command windows